# Set Internet Explorer options for protractor (--headless)

Tags: protractor, end-to-end

I would like to set headless option in my protractor configuration for internet explorer, but I cannot find anyting related to this. They only say how to do it in Chrome and Firefox: Adding chrome and Firefox specific options.

This is what I have so far:

```
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      chromeOptiaons: {
        args: ["--headless"]
      },
    },
    {
      'browserName': 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ["--headless"]
      }
    },
    {
      'browserName': 'internet explorer',
      internetExplorerOptions: {      <---------------------------
        args: ["--headless"]          <---------------------------
      }
    }
  ],
```

internetExplorerOptions is not working

So how do I add the 'Options / args' option to IE?

Answer (score 0):

IE does not have support for a headless mode. But you can try to use [triflejs](http://triflejs.org/).
I did not try this solution by myself but seems like it's the only option since IE is basically obsolete browser and it does not receive any updates.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, "IE does not have support for a headless mode"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need IEDriverServer.

I will try to make this as simple as possible. The proper way to get and install this is, by using protractor’s built-in functionality.
Install Webdriver-manager and gulp, globally.

```
   npm installwebdriver-manager gulp -g
```

Browse to node_modules/protractor/bin and run

```
  npm webdriver-manager --standalone update
  npm webdriver-manager --ie update
```

Then, you will need to manually start the webdriver server

For this, you will need to run

```
   npm webdriver-manager --ie start
```

As simple as that.

After that, the 2nd step is to get the config file right. 
The spicy and “different” stuff is: Capabilities, direct connect, and 
LocalSeleniumStandaloneOpts
Necessary and Important examples for config file, in order to run the spec test suite:

```
capabilities: { 
'browserName': 'internet explorer', 
'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true, 
'platform': 'ANY', 
'version': '11', 
args: ['--silent', '--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--lang=US', '--start-maximized'], //,'--headless', '--disable-gpu' 
prefs: { 
    'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': false, 
        'directory_upgrade': true, 
        'extensions_to_open': '', 
        'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/downloads/'
    }, 
   } 
  }, 
 localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: { 
jvmArgs: [ 
    '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe'
] 
  }, 
  directConnect: false, 
  framework: 'jasmine', 
  seleniumArgs: ['- 
  Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver- 
  manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe'], 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, @yuriy-gerasimovich confirmed that "IE does not have support for a headless mode".

Comment: BTW do you have similar configuration steps for Safari and Protractor?